# Is there an alternative to declaring a slot name in light DOM?

Tags: javascript, browser, web-component, shadow-dom

In shadow DOM v0 developers were not required to know as much about the internal implementation of how/where light DOM content was to be placed in a component's shadow dom.

The v0 specification matched the current behavior of built-in components like `<select>` and `<option>` where the consumer doesn't care as much where specifically their element content would be placed. Instead, the shadow DOM would automatically pick up the elements that match selectors specified in the `select` attribute on a `<content>` tag and place them in the correct location inside the shadow tree. This required less boilerplate on the consuming developer's code.

In v1 you need to know the slot name specifically. Mimicking the same example previously mentioned with `<select>`, I would need to use something like `<option slot="option">` where the slot attribute value specifies where to put the current element. I would also be allowed to add elements that were not intended to be included in that slot like `<table slot="option">`.

In summary, my concerns are:

1. Needing to specify extra information every time I use the webcomponent
2. Having the ability to add invalid elements to the wrong shadow DOM location and have that cause unpredictable side-effects

**In shadow DOM v1 is there a way to get the old behavior of `<content select="option"></content>` where a child has to match a specific selector or it is discarded?** If not, does anyone know why specifically such a big breaking change was made?

**Example 1** (v0 specification)

*index.html*

```
<my-component>
    <my-child-component>Text</my-child-component>
    <wrong-child-component>Wrong</wrong-child-component>
</my-component>
```

*component.html (shadow DOM)*

```
<div>
    <content select="my-child-component"></component>
</div>
```

*resulting DOM*

```
<my-component>
    #shadow-root
        <div>
            <my-child-component>Text</my-child-component>
        </div>
<my-component>
```

**Example 2** (v1 specification)

*index.html*

```
<my-component>
    <my-child-component slot="child-slot">Text</my-child>
    <wrong-child-component slot="child-slot">Wrong</wrong-child-component>
</my-component>
```

*component.html (shadow DOM)*

```
<div>
    <slot name="child-slot"></slot>
</div>
```

*resulting DOM*

```
<my-component>
    #shadow-root
        <div>
            <my-child-component>Text</my-child-component>
            <wrong-child-component>Wrong</wrong-child-component>
        </div>
<my-component>
```

Comment: What issues are you having using version 1 of specification? Can you include links to both version 0 and version 1 specifications at Question?

Comment: Updated my queation @guest271314. Check third paragraph. Thanks.

Comment: Still not following. Though, admittedly, have not tried version 1. Can you create stacksnippets or plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate both approaches, and what you are trying to achieve at version 1 that you are currently implementing at version 0?

Comment: I don't know much about shadow DOM, but I think `slot` is an element, not an attribute. And what do v0 and v1 mean, shadow DOM is still non-versioned working draft.

Comment: I'll get you a snippet as soons as i can make it back to my computer

Comment: @Oriol, slot is an element which has an optional `name` attribute on it. `<slot name="foo"></slot>`. This slot element exists in the element's shadow dom. When someone wants an element in "light dom" to be distributed into the shadow dom, they would specify a `slot` attribute on that element with the name of the corresponding slot as the value: `<p slot="foo">Bar</p>`. This is the v1 version of what `content` was in v0. Also, [here is a link](https://hayato.io/2016/shadowdomv1/#re-distribution-directly-v0-vs-indirectly-by-flattening-v1) to a page describing the v1/v0 differences.

Comment: @guest271314 I have updated my question with some examples. I hope they give more clarity to what I am asking.

Comment: As far as there not being a version... not sure why you'd think that @Oriol: https://hayato.io/2016/shadowdomv1/ .

A similar distinction has similarly been made by one of webcomponent's biggest proponents here: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom

Comment: @WaltWeidner Well, [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/) doesn't have version numbers, just dates. Because it's a draft.

Comment: If result is the same, not certain what issue is?

Comment: 1. Needing to specify extra information everytime you use the webcomponent. 2. Ability to add invalid elements to the wrong shadow DOM location. What is contained in the second to last paragraph.

Comment: @WaltWeidner From the link you shared  _"Blink will continue to support both versions in parallel for some time."_ , _"Calling the older method continues to create a shadow root with v0 semantics, so existing v0 code won't break."_ https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom#historysupport . Is v0 implementation supported at the browsers that you are trying at?

Comment: Generally it is bad practice to implement code in a way you know to be deprecated. I'm not trying to sway the method of implementation in a Stackoverflow question. I just want to know if somehow in my reading I have missed a way of accomplishing the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

To filter the right elements, maybe you can use the [`::slotted( selector )`](https://hayato.io/2016/shadowdomv1/#v1_8) pseudo-element in your Shadow DOM CSS styles:

```
<style>
    ::slotted( :not( option ) )
    {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<slot></slot>
```

...will display only `<option>` elements.

Answer (score 2):

For `v1` there will be no other alternate to `slot`(as far as i have read). But i still don't see the problem. Just like `content` you can use nameless slot also.

Here's an example for [Polymer's 2.0 migration guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade#dom-template)

```
<!-- element template -->
<dom-module id="my-el">
  <template>
   ...
   <h2>
     <slot name="title"></slot>
   </h2>
   <div>
     <slot></slot>
   </div>
 </template>
</dom-module>

...
<!-- usage -->
<my-el>
   <span slot="title">Mr. Darcy</span>
   <span>Fun at parties.</span>
</my-el>
```

[Here's](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1167) one of the discussion on github discussing proposing using slot over content and just to list few advantages of slot over content

> Default slot versus default insertion point. In v0, a default insertion point (one without a select attribute) consumes all nodes not matched by a previous insertion point. In v1, a default slot (one without a name attribute) only matches content with no slot attribute. In other words, a node with a slot attribute is never distributed to the default slot.

Though it has few disadvantages over content also but atleast for now vendors have agreed that slot is the way forward.

Comment: The biggest problem I see is side-effects being caused by adding an improper element to a slot. I guess the consuming developer would figure that out rather quickly though. I guess the difference is that in the past the wrong element just wouldn't exist all all in the shadow DOM whereas now it will fill the slot and cause unpredictable behavior.

Comment: i don't fully get your wrong element argument. I can insert table in v0 also

Comment: Only if you have a catch all `<content>` tag. I'll post a jsfiddle, just a minute.

Comment: Not really. Here's a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/hNBFEXz6Niv4HN94yQs4?p=preview) where i explicitly select table tag

Comment: Check this one out (use Chrome, not polyfilling). The H2 is removed: https://jsfiddle.net/d0Lk0mwc/

Comment: You can easily achieve this behaviour with `slot` also using `name` attribute

Comment: Can you show me an example of that? That is the main thing I want to get out of this question

Comment: Here's a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/g2UnZzoQ82Nz73HoyJST?p=preview). The only difference being(as far as i know) slot cannot use tag name to select

Comment: That is the difference that I am hoping to workaround. I could easily pass the wrong element into the shadow dom in your example just because it has the correct slot name.

Comment: You can have a javascript based check on the child. If it's not what you want you can remove it.

Comment: You can use [slotChanged](https://hayato.io/2016/shadowdomv1/#v1_7) event and can also have [fallback content](https://hayato.io/2016/shadowdomv1/#v1_6) for your slot if needed.